# Maximum Sum Pairs Array List using heap

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, heap

I am trying to print the max numbers (of array size)  which are formed from the sum of ArrayL1.get(i), ArrayL2.get(j) in the descending order. Somehow my code below is not working.I need to get the the time and space complexity of O(n^2 log n) and O(n) respectively.
For instance:
input
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
output
9
8
8

```
    import java.io.*; 
    import java.util.*; 

public class Source {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //below two ArrayList are used to store the given input
        ArrayList<Integer> ArrayL1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ArrayL2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, i;

        // size of ArrayL1 = size of ArrayL2 = n
        n = in.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ArrayL1.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ArrayL2.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        KMaxCombinations(ArrayL1,ArrayL2);
    }
        
    static void KMaxCombinations(ArrayList<Integer> ArrayL1,ArrayList<Integer> ArrayL2)  {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        int N = ArrayL1.size();
                            
         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
                pq.add(ArrayL1[i] + ArrayL2[j]); 
     
        int count = 0; 
          
        while (count < N) 
        { 
            System.out.println(pq.peek()); 
            pq.remove(); 
            count++; 
        } 
                            
                                                   }

      

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are trying to access element from ArrayList using incorrect syntax. Mean you are using below syntax

```
ArrayL1.[i] + ArrayL2.[j]
```

Ideally it should be

```
ArrayL1.get(i) + ArrayL2.get(j)
```

I have updated Source.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Source {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // below two ArrayList are used to store the given input
        ArrayList<Integer> ArrayL1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ArrayL2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, i;

        // size of ArrayL1 = size of ArrayL2 = n
        n = in.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ArrayL1.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ArrayL2.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        KMaxCombinations(ArrayL1, ArrayL2);
    }

    static void KMaxCombinations(ArrayList<Integer> ArrayL1,
            ArrayList<Integer> ArrayL2) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(
                Collections.reverseOrder());
        int N = ArrayL1.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                pq.add(ArrayL1.get(i) + ArrayL2.get(j));

        int count = 0;

        while (count < N) {
            System.out.println(pq.peek());
            pq.remove();
            count++;
        }

    }
}
```

After changing the above syntax, program is giving

Output:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
9
8
8
```

Are you expecting anything else?

Comment: Ah,  How could I miss that part! Thanks alot. It works!! Thank you!!